# Memory Issues When DOM Parsing A Large XML File on Android Devices

Tags: xml, android, dom, memory, parsing

I have an Android application that parses an XML file for users and displays results in a much more mobile friendly format. The app works great for most users, but some users have lots and lots of data and the app crashes on them because it runs out of memory.

Is there any way I have a DOM style XML parser quit parsing data after a certain amount of parsing? I only need the first 30 or so elements so it would make the application much more efficient.

I'd like to use a SAX or pull parser instead, but the XML I'm parsing is **not valid** and I have no control over it. Unless anyone has some good SAX solutions that let me parse messy, invalid XML, I think DOM is the only way to go.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: That seems like a bit of an impossible task...  

By not valid, do you mean that the xml is not schema valid?  Or that it is not well formed xml at all?  Are the elements you care about grouped under a common parent?  

You might be able to pull out just that part of the xml using some other means, and then just parse that.

I don't know of any dom parsers that let you call it quits partway through.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the XML is HTML, and it has all sorts of unescaped entities that were causing the SAX parser to crash. All I need to do with it is pull out the first 10 instances of an element with a certain class.

Comment: Ah, I see.  You might look for tools for converting your html into xhtml.  There are a few out there, although I don't know how they'd perform in android.  Alternatively, http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/ claims to be a sax parser for malformed html.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution, but here's what I ended up doing.

I'm using HTTPClient to grab the files, I figured out what the smallest possible size of the file could be where it still has the amount of the data I need and used that information to set the range header of the request.

This causes the request to only return a partial response, but it works in my situation.